# External data does not load in excel when scheduled from scheduled task

Tags: excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

The problem is I made a script that opens and refreshes data in my excel.
The data is external data from a PHD server I get this data with a plugin installed on excel.
All works fine untill I try to schedule the script with task scheduler. when I schedule it as "**run only when user is logged on**" it workes fine. but when I try to schedule it as " **run wheter user is logged on or not**" it does not update the data.
(it does open the excel and saves it but no changes in the data)

It is set on a VM that acts as a desktop and the updates need to be done even when i'm logged of.

The code of the script: (that works fine when i manualy launch it)

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'launch excel.
oExcel.Visible = True ' makes the aplication visible (if not set to true the  data won't be updated) 
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False' disables all excel allerts.
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False 'now excel will not ask you to update links.
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False 'excel will not display an alert before overwriting data in a cell.
```

code for the plugin to update data

```
Dim addIn 
addIn = COMAddIn
Dim automationObject 
automationObject =  Object
Set addIn = oExcel.COMAddIns("ExcelCompanion")
Set automationObject = addIn.Object
automationObject.UNIF_workbook_refresh
```

code to save and close excel

```
oWorkbook.RefreshAll 'refreshes the workbook
oWorkbook.Save 'saves the updated workoob
oWorkbook.Final = True 'makes the file read-only
oExcel.Quit 'exits excel
Set oWorkbook = Nothing ' destroy the object (minimises damage if the object goes out of scope)
Set oExcel = Nothing    ' destroy the object (minimises damage if the object goes out of scope)
```

these 3 block of code form the script.

Answer (score 0):

Hencky!

Which version of Windows do you have? I had the same problem about a week ago, and I came across a very strange solution... :)

Try adding a folder into C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile, simply named "Desktop"... If you run a 32-bit version of Windows, do the same thing except the path must contain system32 instead of SysWOW64...
The "run wheter user is logged on or not" will now do the work... If you had a logging function in your script, you would've seen that the script stops somewhere arround Excel commands... I don't know why is that so, it simply is...